# Who influenced the orcs of Mount Gram to attack Eriador?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Orcs seem to rarely attack without some higher influence behind them.

Is it possible Sauron ordered the king of Mount Gram Golfimbul to attack Eriador?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately we can't really say one way or the other; there just aren't enough details. It's certainly possible, since we know that Sauron was in Dol Guldur at the time:

> 2460<sup>1</sup> The Watchful Peace ends. Sauron returns with increased strength to Dol Guldur.<sup>2</sup>

We also know that Sauron is active around this time:

> *c.* 2480 Orcs begin to make secret strongholds in the Misty Mountains so as to bar all the passes into Eriador. Sauron begins to people Moria with his creatures.

Meanwhile, the event you speak of takes place almost 200 years later:

> 2747 Bandobras Took defeats an Orc-band in the Northfarthing.

There's a little bit more in Appendix A: Annals of the Kings and Rulers I, The Númenórean Kings, (iii): "Eriador, Arnor, and the Heirs of Isildur":

> And later in the days of Arassuil<sup>3</sup>, Orcs, multiplying again in the Misty Mountains, began to ravage the lands *[...]* It was at this time that a large band came so far west as to enter the Shire, and were driven off by Bandobras Took.

It seems likely to assume that these orcs, led by Golfimbul, were the ancestors of the goblins who would waylay Thorin and company during the Quest for Erebor. Unfortunately these goblins are far less chatty in the book than in the movies, and they say nothing in their brief appearance to suggest one way or the other whether they were working with Sauron.

But that's all the information I can gather through *The Hobbit*, *The Lord of the Rings*, and a perusal of Tolkien's letters. *History of Middle-Earth* may have more details, but I find it unlikely; this event is really nothing more than a footnote in the history of Middle-Earth.

---

<sup>1</sup> All dates are in the Third Age

<sup>2</sup> Except where noted, all quotes are from Appendix B: The Tale of Years, *The Third Age*

<sup>3</sup> 11th Chieftain of the Dúnedain, and Aragorn's great-great-great grandfather